# Why is this Rails submit_tag disabling itself when I check a checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, simple-form

I'm running into a strange issue when trying to add a checkbox (for a boolean field) to my form(s). The forms works perfectly when just updating text fields or file fields but since I added in a boolean field checkbox, upon checking any of the checkboxes, the submit form button "disables" itself.

I can't seem to figure out how or where from Rails is doing this behind the scenes:

My code is as below:

```
<%= simple_form_for @resource, url: resources_path do |f| %>
<div class="form-items">

  <div class="form-item full">
    <%= f.input :name, autofocus: true %>
  </div> <!-- /.form-item full -->

  <div class="form-item">
    <%= f.input :file, as: :file %>
  </div> <!-- /.form-item -->

  <div class="form-item">
    <%= f.input :public_file %>
  </div> <!-- /.form-item -->

</div> <!-- /.form-items -->

<%= f.button :submit, 'Add Resource', class: 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

`public_file` is the boolean field which is marked as:

```
t.boolean  "public_file",       default: false
```

in the database schema

The submit button starts out with this rendered HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add Resource" class="btn button" data-disable-with="Add Resource">
```

but as soon as I check the checkbox:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add Resource" class="btn button" data-disable-with="Add Resource" disabled>
```

I'm not really too sure how to debug this and haven't found any documentation on Rails automatically disabling forms? Could that be what is happening?

Any pointers greatly received!

Comment: your form object is 'f' then what is 't' in 't.boolean  "public_file",       default: false'

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay sorry that is in the database schema

Answer (score 0):

just replace your

```
<%= f.input :public_file %>
```

with

```
<%= f.check_box :public_file %>
```

Hope, It will work.

Comment: Thanks Hardik, using simple_form though it takes a slightly different syntax

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't the correct answer though, see above.

Comment: there is different way to doing same thing its depend on you what you adapt

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable default validation with `novalidate` option. To add 'public_file' as checkbox use `as: :boolean`.

```
<%= simple_form_for @resource, url: resources_path, html: { novalidate: true } do |f| %>
<%= f.input :public_file, as: :boolean %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, worth knowing even if the problem ended up being a lack of JS isolation!

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was a victim of not correctly isolating my Javascript functions. Another function intended for another page was causing the issue.

Sorry for this, have started trying to add body classes and using a statement like the following for isolating (as well as one can) JS in Rails:

```
return unless $('.students.index').length > 0
```